# Moving Average grouped by two separate columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains scores for an Away team as well as a Home team.

```
DF = data.frame(Away = c("A","B","C","B","A","C"), Home = c("B","C","A","A","C","B"), 
                AwayPts = c(10,22,12,14,25,10), HomePts = c(11,14,13,15,15,13))

Away Home AwayPts HomePts
A    B    10      11
B    C    22      14
C    A    12      13
B    A    14      15
A    C    25      15
C    B    10      13
```

I am trying to find the lagged (k=1) rolling average of "Pts" for each team, regardless if they were the Away or Home team. I want two columns added like this...

```
Away Home AwayPts HomePts AwayMA HomeMA
A    B    10      11      NA     NA
B    C    22      14      NA     NA
C    A    12      13      NA     NA
B    A    14      15      16.5   11.5   # (16.5=(22+11)/2) (11.5=(13+10)/2)
A    C    25      15      14     13
C    B    10      13      13.5   18
```

So far, the code I have to create the "AwayMA" column is this...but I want to somehow add HomePts to the rollapplyr function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

DF = DF %>% group_by(Away, Home) %>% mutate(AwayMA = lag(rollapplyr(AwayPts, 2, mean, fill = NA),k=1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this using base R functions as follows:

```
d <- reshape(DF, matrix(1:4, 2, byrow = TRUE), dir="long")
e <- d[order(d$Away,d$id),]
e$AwayPts= unlist(tapply(e$AwayPts, e$Away,filter, filter=c(0,1,1)/2, sides=1))
e <- e[order(e$time, e$id),]
attributes(e) <- attributes(d)
cbind(DF, reshape(e)[c("AwayPts", "HomePts")])

    Away Home AwayPts HomePts AwayPts HomePts
1.1    A    B      10      11      NA      NA
2.1    B    C      22      14      NA      NA
3.1    C    A      12      13      NA      NA
4.1    B    A      14      15    16.5    11.5
5.1    A    C      25      15    14.0    13.0
6.1    C    B      10      13    13.5    18.0
```

---

Note that the `filter` function is the one from the `stats` package. If you have loaded `dply` or even `tidyverse` it is masked. And you have to unmask it before you could use it:

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider the following. Would put into long format with `pivot_longer`, which would be easier to calculate rolling mean by grouping by "Team" only. If you rename "Away" and "Home" columns, it is easier to combine teams (and since the points columns both end in "Pts" they are already set). After calculating the rolling mean, you can put back into wide form with `pivot_wider`. The `Game` column is helpful for putting back into wide form as an id column.

**Edit**: Thank you to G. Grothendieck to simplify the rolling mean. Using `list(-(1:2))` for width will include offsets of -1 and -2, eliminating the need for `lag`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

DF %>%
  rename_at(vars(Away, Home), ~ str_c(., "Team")) %>%
  mutate(Game = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Game, 
               names_to = c("Location", ".value"), 
               names_pattern = "(\\w+)(Team|Pts)") %>%
  group_by(Team) %>%
  mutate(MA = rollapply(Pts, list(-(1:2)), mean, fill = NA)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Game, names_from = Location, values_from = c(Team, Pts, MA))
```

**Output**

```
   Game Team_Away Team_Home Pts_Away Pts_Home MA_Away MA_Home
  <int> <chr>     <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 A         B               10       11    NA      NA  
2     2 B         C               22       14    NA      NA  
3     3 C         A               12       13    NA      NA  
4     4 B         A               14       15    16.5    11.5
5     5 A         C               25       15    14      13  
6     6 C         B               10       13    13.5    18
```